# Make SFSafariViewController rotate with device to match orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am creating an instance of an SFSafariViewController from within a tableVC.  When the SafariVC is open, the orientation of it does not change (portrait to landscape, vice versa) when the device is rotated.  Is there a quick fix to this? I tried to use some layout anchors on the SafariVC and that caused a crash.  Code below:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
    SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]initWithURL:URL entersReaderIfAvailable:YES];
    [sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too late for you, but are you using only the Simulator for testing?
I had the same issue, but it works properly on the device.